# Monerod crashes on startup - Failed to create SSL certificate

Tags: monerod, daemon, compile

I am attempting to run a Monero daemon on my Ubuntu 16.04 machine. I followed [these](https://github.com/moneroexamples/compile-monero-09-on-ubuntu-16-04) steps to compile monero, and have successfully compiled the binaries required to run a Monero daemon.

When I run `sudo ./monerod` in my `~/monero/build/Linux/master/release/bin` folder, the daemon starts, but when it attempts to generate an SSL certificate after initializing the core RPC server, I receive the error:

`ERROR net.ssl contrib/epee/include/net/abstract_tcp_server2.inl:970 Error starting server: Failed to create certificate`

My daemon then shuts down. What step have I missed?

Comment: Could you open this issue on the Monero Github too? https://github.com/monero-project/monero/issues/new

Comment: And please post the log with --log-level 1 on the bug you open.

Comment: The instructions you linked are hideously old and not the [official instructions](https://github.com/monero-project/monero#compiling-monero-from-source).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are compiling the *master* branch (which includes an SSL [commit/PR](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/commit/24569454086a366e0bd0cd9b33b0b34661fe7af8)). I would advise building the most recent *release* tag / branch, as documented in the official [compilation instructions](https://github.com/monero-project/monero#compiling-monero-from-source).

Note, the most recent release tag is currently v0.14.0.2 so can be checked out with `git checkout v0.14.0.2` after you have cloned.

Answer (score 3):

Fixed in PR#5257 https://github.com/monero-project/monero/pull/5257

Skipping extra unnecessary cruft.